# Bootstrap classes change when deployed to IIS 7

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, deployment, twitter-bootstrap-3, iis-7

I've got an issue when deploying to IIS 7, my css classes change, i am using the bootstrap in the ASP.NET MVC Framework,

This is the application in the development environment,

Development Environment

[image]

Deployed Environment

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: share your code instead of images

Comment: Try F12 and look for 404 errors on css files.  Also, bundling behaves differently if the app is not in debug mode.

Comment: Try adding `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` to your BundleConfig class in your dev environment, then try it locally, if it now breaks locally the bundling is causing the issue.